# Wikipedia Search Page

Tags: jquery

I have created a code for a wikipedia search page using jquery with this thus far.....

```
<script>
$("#search").on("click", function() {
 var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();
  console.log(searchTerm);
  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php? 
   action=opensearch&search="+ searchTerm     
          + "&list=10&format=json&callback=?";
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "Get",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
      $("#search").html(data);
      console.log(data);
      for (var i = 0; i < data.data[9].length; i++) {
      }
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

......

However, when the data populates to the website it produces one long string like this.....

hatsHat,Hatshepsut,Hatsukaichi Station,Hats Off to the Bull,Hatsune Miku,Hatsuharu-class destroyer,.....DIVA ArcadeA hat is a head covering which is worn for various reasons, including protection against the elements, ceremonial... Project DIVA-) is a series of rhythm games created by Sega and Crypton Future Media  I want a list of ten url to possibly search....etc.etc

How do I code it to where I make the reults show 10 separate links which I can search?  I appreciate the help.  Thanks

Comment: split on `,` and build the links while looping the split array

Comment: @pedro  thanks, the links are list in the results.  I did not copy the whole result.  However, are you suggesting using a for loop function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've played a little with your code and come with something that you may want to use:

```js
$("#go").on("click", function() {
  $('#output').empty();
  var searchTerm = $("#searchTerm").val();
  var url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + searchTerm + "&list=10&format=json&callback=?";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "Get",
    async: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data[3].length; i++) {
        $('#output').append($('<a>').attr('href', data[3][i]).text(data[1][i])).append("<br>").html();
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchTerm">
<input type="submit" id="go"  value="Wiki Me">
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: just checked it out. works perfectly.  Appreciate your input @pedro.  thanks